# Multiple If formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

How can I put this formula in Code form. need to paste this formula from A7 till the last cell

=IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDLA","OP LAB",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDCL","DCL",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AECAL","CAL",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDXB","DXB OPS",0))))

Any advise as There is an error in below code in line
rng.Formula = "=IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDLA","OP
LAB",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDCL","DCL",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AECAL","CAL",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDXB","DXB OPS",0))))"

```
 Sub Dubai()

 Dim lr As Long
 Dim rng As Range


Sheets("00689").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BU"

     lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     
Set rng = Range("A7:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Formula = "=IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDLA","OP LAB",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDCL","DCL",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AECAL","CAL",IF(LEFT(E8,5)="AEDXB","DXB OPS",0))))"
rng.Value = rng.Formula

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Jenny

Comment: Use a lookup table?

Comment: Formula needs to be updated in VBA before implementation, please see my response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the portion within quotes like below screenshot and then replace all quotes with pair of quotes using `Find and Replace` with red marked options.

[image]

The outcome will be as below:

```
Rng.Formula = "=IF(LEFT(E8,5)=""AEDLA"",""OP LAB"",IF(LEFT(E8,5)=""AEDCL"",""DCL"",IF(LEFT(E8,5)=""AECAL"",""CAL"",IF(LEFT(E8,5)=""AEDXB"",""DXB OPS"",0))))"
Rng.Value = Rng.Value
```

Next code line shall also be updated as demonstrated above.